# What does the unity/compiz error "FBO is incomplete" mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: unity, compiz

I am having trouble with Unity after an upgrade to 14.04 (and still there after another update to 14.10 which was due to me not paying attention)

I have no unity or anything else and only have Firefox because being the very nice app that it is it loaded for me to carry on where it left off.

I can drop to TTY1 and `DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace` but the error message I get is

> compiz (opengl) - error: FBO is incomplete: GL:FRAMEBUFFER UNSUPPORTED

What is it trying to tell me and how can I fix this?

UPDATE 1: I tried following the advice here: [upgraded to 14.10 and no unity no dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541005/upgraded-to-14-10-and-no-unity-no-dash) but this was not the answer I was looking for.

UPDATE 2: Using `DISPLAY=:0 ccsm` I was able to enable to the Unity plugin for compiz and disable Framebuffer Object in OpenGL `DISPLAY=:0 compiz` then gives me the unity sidebar although the top bar is pretty limited and lacks menus etc.

Comment: I would suggest doing a re-install of 14.04 or 14.10 (make a backup of your  personal data if needed). You can turn the framebuffer off with CCSM but you need a desktop for that ;)

Comment: I'd rather solve and fix the problem if I possibly can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed things for me.

I dropped to tty1 using `ctrl`+`alt`+`F1` and typed `DISPLAY=:0 ccsm` `ctrl`+`alt`+`F7` I switched back and using CCSM I was able to enable to the Unity plugin for compiz and disable Framebuffer Object in the OpenGL plugin.

Then back to tty1 and

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

I rebooted and everything is working fine.