# System won't boot / black screen after upgrade to 15.04, macbook pro 11,5

Tags: boot, upgrade, graphics, 15.04

I have a new macbbook pro 11,5 with retina display.

I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed alongside OSX Yosemite 10.10.3, using rEFInd as the boot manager.

All was fine until I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 today using the command: sudo do-release-upgrade

The upgrade appeared to go well, the system was restarted and now when I boot into Ubuntu I get a black screen.

I have managed to get into recovery mode (grub root shell prompt)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: update - I have reinstalled rEFInd and nowI get the choice of which volume to boot from. When I choose the Ubuntu volume it starts to load but then I just get a black screen. Please help!

Comment: I managed to resolve this issue myself.

Comment: Firstly, the upgrade that was supposed to be to 15.04 actually only took me to 10.1

Comment: I realised I could actually log in to command line with ctrl+alt+f1

Comment: All the programs seemed to be running, just not unity / compiz. This little gem fixed the issue: rm -rf .compiz-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue myself.

Firstly, the upgrade that was supposed to be to 15.04 actually only took me to 10.1. Presumably something baulked half way through.

I realised I could actually log in to command line with ctrl+alt+f1 – all the programs seemed to run fine, just not unity / compiz.

This little gem fixed the issue:

```
rm -rf .compiz-1
```

I got it here: [upgraded to 14.10 and no unity no dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541005/upgraded-to-14-10-and-no-unity-no-dash)

Comment: Thanks for documenting your updates, prob gonna need this when I install ubuntu on my macbook